# Get Latest Record per "OtherUser" Parse Core Database

Tags: ios, database, swift, parsing, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to develop a simple chat system in my Swift-based iOS app. So far, I have two Classes defined in Parse: User (defines a user) and Message (defines a single message sent to a user). Here's my Message class fields:

```
UserFromID (pointer): points to the User object that sent the message
UserToID (pointer): points to the User object that receives the message
createdAt (DateTime): creation point in time (built-in field)
Content (string): the textual message to show the user
```

On the conversation selection screen, I want to display a table listing every user that the signed-in user has interacted with. I also want to grab the last message recorded in that conversation, regardless of who sent it between the two users in that conversation. I've been able to do this, but in a wasteful manner:

```
// get all messages sent FROM and TO the user
let primaryObj = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: self.userID)
let fromQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")
let toQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")

// add constraints to both queries
fromQuery.whereKey("UserFromID", equalTo: primaryObj)
toQuery.whereKey("UserToID", equalTo: primaryObj)

// generate the concatenated query, include User access, and return sorted
let masterQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([fromQuery, toQuery])
masterQuery.includeKey("UserFromID")
masterQuery.includeKey("UserToID")
masterQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")

// execute the query, and perform response logic
masterQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // query logic goes here...
})
```

This works, but again, it returns all messages sent to and from the signed-in user between all users. I only want the most recent message between each user. The current solution would incur lots of overhead, and I think Parse's hard limit for object requests is 1000. It's pretty easy for two users to send 1000 messages between each other within a month, or even a week, depending on user. My solution would require many large queries per device, neglecting caching initiatives, and my requests will be through the roof just from chat. Especially when the data requirement is so low.

What I'd like my fromQuery and toQuery to do is grab messages with the greatest createdAt field (DateTime) on a per-unique otherUser basis.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should do is put limits to the fromQuery and the toQuery like this:

```
fromQuery.limit = 1
toQuery.limit = 1
```

This way you will always get only 2 results. Then when you get the result just compare the createdAt property of the 2 results.